# vowpal wabbit using multiple data files (for timeseries crossvalidation)

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Hi I am trying to run a timeseries crossvalidation in a "rolling window" style:  ie train with 8 weeks of data, test with next week, slide 1 week along.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

I have split my data file into weekly chunks.  So what I was hoping was to pass in multiple files to the --data parameter  (I was trying repeated --data).

This doesn't work, but it seems like one can use multiple cache files.  AFAIK, this would require me to first create the cache file chunks out of my text file chunks.  I am not clear how I would call vw to just create cache files?

Comment: I forget the parameter settings, but it is easy to generate cache files ( and no training) to support this use case

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the data on the stdin (concatenate all the files with `cat`). However, as `vw` does online learning by default, there is no need to do manually the "rolling window" (and cache files) unless you want to use multiple training passes. Just store the model (with `--save_resume -f path/to/the.model`) and next week just continue training with the new data.

Comment: Hi, yes I want to do multiple passes. so I could do what you suggest for 1 pass. it all seems a bit clumsy :)

Comment: For multiple passes you have to create the cache file, but you can still pipe the training data to `vw`'s stdin (if you don't want to create a temp train file with all weeks). BTW: for cross-validation you can use `holdout_after` to specify that e.g. the last week is the dev set and the rest train set.